# Optimize query to minimize tmp copying time

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, temporary-tables

I have a query when Checking the profile i get this :

[image]

I read in order to optimize this i'll have to work on my joins .

I also added index on the fields that i'm grouping by (date_seance , heure_debut) in the main table (seance_pratique)

[image]

Is there something i can do to make it faster ?

**Update 1** (EXPLAIN QUERY):

[image]

Comment: An EXPLAIN would help.Also a combined index on the fields in the WHERE clause in order and in the same table.

Comment: @Mihai I've added the explain image

Answer (score 1):

Review indexing on cours table as you're getting a full table scan there.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots

Great indexing tips there ^

Comment: Good Tips ...but not exactly what i'm looking for ... tips are very generic .